# Eclipse - don't automatically add parenthesis

Tags: java, eclipse, settings, formatter, eclipse-formatter

We use a shared `Java - Code Style - Formatter`, `Checkstyle` and some other settings across all projects in Eclipse for all developers, which is great.
I'm annoyed by one of the settings however and want to change it, but I don't know where this setting is.

It's currently changing something like this:

```
if (something > 0 || something <= x) {
  ...
}
```

automatically to this:

```
if ((something > 0) || (something <= x)) {
  ...
}
```

Does anyone know where in Eclipse I can change this setting so it keeps the first (or even better, change the latter to the first)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can set this setting using Preferences--> Java --> Editor--> Save Actions--> Code Style.
Deselect "Use parentheses in expressions". It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Completely forgot about the `Save Actions` in the Preferences.. I looked at `Checkstyle`, `Formatter`, `Typing`, `Editor`, etc.